# react-redux: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I am creating CRUD app with react-redux and [json server fake api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server), now I can add, delete and edit but I have problem with adding an item, I get error.  `Request failed with status code 404`

Here is my live app in sandobox : [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/throne1986/reduxa?file=/src/redux/acitons/users/Users.js)

Here is my action function to add users.

```
export const addNewUser = data => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/users/")
    .then(response =>{
      dispatch(addUser(data));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      const errorMsg = error.message;
      dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(errorMsg));
    })
  }
}
```

and here is my form to add user

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { editUser, updateUser } from "../redux/acitons/users/Users";

function UserForm({ user }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [name, setName] = useState(user.name);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(name);
    dispatch(updateUser({ ...user, name }));
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    dispatch(editUser(user.id));
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{user.id}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          defaultValue={user.name}
          onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" className="btn outline" onClick={handleCancel}>
          <i className="material-icons">Cancel</i>
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-success btn-link"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          <i className="material-icons">save</i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default UserForm;
```

What is wrong with my codes? any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: A 404 status code means that the route POST http://localhost:3000/users/ does not exist on the server side. You should try to remove this trailing slash or verify in json server fake api that this route is advertised. cc https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404. If you give me more information about the API and what you have done on the server side i could help.

Comment: @Poulpy am just using json server fake api so I just have users,json file and I run json-server --watch users.json which gives me endpoints, that is it

Comment: `404` is a server error - nothing to do with your `client-side` code

Comment: @goto1 then what is wrong am I doing? u check the code